# Creating Directories: with Permissions

Tags: filesystems, permissions, osx

I need to create a directory that is RW to all users using chown. what arguments should I pass chown to get a file with those permissions? Or maybe there is an even better way to do it......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`chown` is used to change ownership; you're looking for `chmod` to change the mode. You want to add (`+`) read and write (`rw`) for all users (`a`), so it's:

```
$ chmod a+rw dirname
```

You can also do it directly when you make the directory by passing `mkdir` the `-m` flag; it takes the same syntax as `chmod`:

```
$ mkdir -m a+rw dirname
```

Comment: I get permission denied, & the way I want to implement this I can't authenticate using sudo

Comment: @Samantha You got it making a new directory or changing the mode of a directory you own?

Comment: I managed to make it work by running the mkdir from the /bin/mkdir. Thx for all the help